# Writting more event to channel leads to channel full exception

Tags: flume-ng

I am using the flume JMS source to dequeue message from ActiveMQ and convert this message into `List<Event>` using custom converter

**Channel configuration**

```
agent.channels.c1.type = memory
agent.channels.c1.capacity = 1000000
agent.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 1500
```

when size of the `List<Event>` is less than or equal to 1500 (channel transaction capacity),then flume write the events to channel , but if the event size is greater than 1500 then  i am getting the below exception

**Error log**

```
21 Apr 2015 12:19:28,245 WARN  [PollableSourceRunner-JMSSource-s1] (org.apache.flume.source.jms.JMSSource.doProcess:263)  - Error appending event to channel. Channel might be full. Consider increasing the channel capacity or make sure the sinks perform faster.
org.apache.flume.ChannelException: Unable to put batch on required channel: org.apache.flume.channel.MemoryChannel{name: c1}
    at org.apache.flume.channel.ChannelProcessor.processEventBatch(ChannelProcessor.java:200)
    at org.apache.flume.source.jms.JMSSource.doProcess(JMSSource.java:257)
    at org.apache.flume.source.AbstractPollableSource.process(AbstractPollableSource.java:54)
    at org.apache.flume.source.PollableSourceRunner$PollingRunner.run(PollableSourceRunner.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.flume.ChannelException: Put queue for MemoryTransaction of capacity 1500 full, consider committing more frequently, increasing capacity or increasing thread count
    at org.apache.flume.channel.MemoryChannel$MemoryTransaction.doPut(MemoryChannel.java:84)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicTransactionSemantics.put(BasicTransactionSemantics.java:93)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicChannelSemantics.put(BasicChannelSemantics.java:80)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.ChannelProcessor.processEventBatch(ChannelProcessor.java:189)
    ... 4 more
```

How to solve this problem?

**Note:** Event size varies dynamically based on ActiveMQ message

Comment: I think the logs already point to the solution: Consider increasing the channel capacity or make sure the sinks perform faster (or adding more threads/sinks). Even, committing more frequently. Just think this a typical producer-consumer problem, where the producers are faster than the consumers.

Comment: Don't worry about the messages size since the queue size is measured in events, not bytes.

Comment: @frb how can i increase capacity because Event size varies dynamically based on ActiveMQ message am getting

Comment: As alrady said, Flume channels capacity is not measured in bytes, but in number of events that can be stored; this means it does not matter if the events have 10KB size or 1MB size. The keypoint regarding your scenario is the frequency the events are generated and processed. So you have two options: (1) generate the events slowly, or (2) process the events faster.